# How to expose a .NET 5.0 Component to COM for use in VBA

Tags: c#, com, .net-5

so I am currently migrating my project from .NET Framework 4.7.2 to .NET 5.0. The old project exposes some functionality via COM so it can be used in Excel's VBA. For .NET Framework this could easily be done by using regasm. However, as far as I understand it regasm is not available for .NET 5.0 or any .NET Core version.
As stated here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/native-interop/expose-components-to-com) the COM host can be registered using regsvr32 which works fine but no .tlb is created. Thus, I manually wrote an IDL file to produce the tlb as suggested in the above resource and compiled it with the Midl compiler. The tlb is generated but the types are not recognized when I try to use it in Excel.

I created a little test project to try it out which looks like this:
Interface that should be made available:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace test
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("myGUID"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface IServer : IDisposable
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        double Addition();

        [ComVisible(true)]
        double Subtraction();

        event CalcResultDelegate CalcResultChanged;

    }
}
```

The class that implements the interface:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace test
{
    [Guid("anotherGUID"), ProgId("test")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Server : IServer
    {
        public event CalcResultDelegate CalcResultChanged;

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public double Addition()
        {
            return 4 + 4;
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public double Subtraction()
        {
            return 4 - 0;
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dispose");
        }

    }
}
```

The idl file I created:

```
import "ocidl.idl";
import "unknwn.idl";
[
    object,
    uuid(GUID),
    dual
]
interface test : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT Addition([out, retval] double* result);

    HRESULT Subtraction([out, retval] double* result);
};
[
    uuid(GUID),
    helpstring("test tlb"),
    version(1.0)
]
library testTlb
{
    importlib("stdole32.tlb");
    interface test;

    [ uuid(GUID)]
    coclass LibTest
    {
        interface test;
    };
}
```

I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction or suggest any alternative approach!

Comment: The coclass guid is wrong.

Comment: You can use .NET Framework to build a .tlb (regasm /tlb), it's often easier (or at least a good starting point), you don't have to build it yourself.

Comment: I am using a different GUID for the coclass than I did for the library. Do I need to remove it or how is it supposed to look like?  I used this article as a reference. [link](https://thrysoee.dk/InsideCOM+/ch03b.htm)

Comment: @SimonMourier This is what I am doing at the moment and it works fine. However, I would like the complete project to be deployed with .NET 5.0 rather than using .NET Framework.

Comment: Yes I got that. I'm saying TLB are .NET independent. You can use .NET Framework generated TLB with .NET 5

Comment: Have you tried to use Regasm to register dll and create a tlb file?

Comment: Thanks to SimonMourier's suggestion I was able to create a small test project using the tlb generated by .NET Framework and modifying it a little. However, as this is quite error-prone and not really feasible for a COM object with more functionality I used a C/C++ header instead.